# Customize a TextView (text appearance) in Android Studio (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, textview

bear with me as I am new to android studio with the Kotlin language.

I have declared a `textView` object in my `activity_main.xml` file. I am trying to customise the font, font size, and text colour of this `textView`. I have been able to do so by customising each attribute individually; however, this is quickly getting tedious for my other `activity.xml` files.

I know that there is a `textAppearance` property that holds all these values. How can I declare a custom `textAppearence` so that I no longer need to change these values independently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define custom styles in a styles.xml file located at: res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="GreenText">
<item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
</style>
```

It can be applied via:

```
<TextView style="@style/GreenText"... />
```